# edit .doc file header java

Tags: java, apache-poi, doc

I need to edit .doc & .docx files header and maintain the style of the document.

I tried doing it by using:

1. poi api :  I managed to read the file header but couldn't find how to replace a text in it and save the result with the original style .

   ```
   public static void mFix(String iFilePath , HashMap<String, String> iOldNewCouples) 
   {

       aOldNewCouples = iOldNewCouples;

        try {
            if(iFilePath==null)
                return;

              File  file = new File(iFilePath);
              FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
              HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
              WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(document); // read the doc as rtf

              String fileData = extractor.getHeaderText();
              String fileDataResult =fileData ;

              for (Entry<String, String> entry : aOldNewCouples.entrySet())
              {
                   if(fileData.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                        System.out.println("replace " +entry.getKey());
                       fileDataResult = fileData.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); 
                     } 
              }
              document.getHeaderStoryRange().replaceText(fileData, fileDataResult);
              saveWord(iFilePath ,document);
              fis.close();


       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace( );
       }

   }

   private static void saveWord(String filePath, HWPFDocument doc) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
   {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
               try{
                   fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath.replace(".doc", "-test.doc")));
                   BufferedOutputStream buffOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                   doc.write(buffOutputStream);
                   buffOutputStream.close();
                   fileOutputStream.close();


               }
               finally{
                 if( fileOutputStream != null)
                     fileOutputStream.close();
               }
   }
   ```
2. I tried doc4j api for docx : I found how to edit the header but didn't found how to keep the style.

   ```
   public static void mFix(String iFilePath , HashMap<String, String> iOldNewCouples) {

       aOldNewCouples = iOldNewCouples;
       WordprocessingMLPackage output;
       try {
           output = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(iFilePath));
           replaceText(output.getDocumentModel().getSections().get(0).getHeaderFooterPolicy().getDefaultHeader());
           output.save(new File(iFilePath));
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   public static void replaceText(ContentAccessor c)    throws Exception
   {
       for (Object p: c.getContent())
       {
         if (p instanceof ContentAccessor)
           replaceText((ContentAccessor) p);

         else if (p instanceof JAXBElement)
         {
           Object v = ((JAXBElement) p).getValue();

           if (v instanceof ContentAccessor)
             replaceText((ContentAccessor) v);

           else if (v instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Text)
           {
             org.docx4j.wml.Text t = (org.docx4j.wml.Text) v;
             String text = t.getValue();
             if (text != null)
             {
                 boolean flag = false;
                 for (Entry<String, String> entry : aOldNewCouples.entrySet())
                  {
                       if(text.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                           flag =true;
                           text = text.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                            t.setSpace("preserve"); 
                            t.setValue(text);

                         } 
                  }
               }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   ```

I would like to have examples for those api.

If there is other free solution for this for Java projects , please write them with example.

thanks

Tami

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: I added my code , sorry that it is not added nice...

Comment: could you replace the header texts by preserving the format?@tamih